# $\ell^2$-summability of a convergent sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

For each $n\in\mathbb N$ consider $f_n:\{1,2,\dots,n\}\rightarrow [0,1]$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^n f_n(i) = 1$. Now assume that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_n(i) = 0$ for each $i\in\mathbb N$. Is it true that in that case $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{i=1}^nf_n(i)^2 = 0?\qquad\qquad(\star)$$
My attempt was to assume that for each $n\in\mathbb N$, $f_n$ can be written as $f_n(i) = g_n\cdot h(i)$, where $g_n$ is a sequence independent of $i$ with $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} g_n = 0$. Clearly, this is a strong assumption and I don't know yet it can be justified. What would be the right way to approach this question? Does this question even make sense with regard to well-definedness?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this example...
$$
f_n(i) = \begin{cases}
1 & i = n
\\
0 & i \ne n
\end{cases}
$$
Then
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n f_n(i) = 1,\qquad
\sum_{n=1}^n f_n(i)^2 = 1,\qquad
\\
\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(i) = 0 ,\qquad
\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^n f_n(i)^2 = 1.
$$

Comment: wow, thank you! This is a very neat example.